# Proxy on DOM element gives error when returning functions that implement interface Element

Tags: javascript, dom, proxy

I have set up a proxy on a DOM element, in this case a XUL element `<browser>`.  The proxy works fine, except when I want to return certain functions that require the element to implement interface Element, I get an error.

The proxy I am actually using is more complex, but reducing things down, my test proxy is as follows:

```
let gB = {

  NS_XUL : "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul",
  browser : document.createElementNS(this.NS_XUL, "browser"),

  addTab : function() {

    let tab = document.createElementNS(this.NS_XUL, "tab");

    tab.linkedBrowser = new Proxy(this.browser,{
      "get": function (target, key) {
        if (key in target) {
          return target[key];
        }
      },
    });
    return tab;
  },  
}
```

When I run the following code:

```
let tab1 = gB.addTab()
try {
  dump("      1 > "+tab1.linkedBrowser.getBoundingClientRect()+"\n");
}catch(e) { dump("ERROR 1 : "+e+"\n"); }
```

I get this output:

```
ERROR 1 : TypeError: 'getBoundingClientRect' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.
```

What is extremely puzzling to me, is that I can run the same function on the element directly, and get no error, yet I can compare the two functions for equality, and it shows that they are the very same object:

```
let tab1 = gB.addTab()
dump("equals? : "+(tab1.linkedBrowser.getBoundingClientRect === gB.browser.getBoundingClientRect)+"\n");
try {
  dump("      1 > "+tab1.linkedBrowser.getBoundingClientRect()+"\n");
}catch(e) { dump("ERROR 1 : "+e+"\n"); }
try {
  dump("      2 > "+gB.browser.getBoundingClientRect()+"\n");
}catch(e) { dump("ERROR 2 : "+e+"\n"); }
```

I get this output:

```
equals? : true
ERROR 1 : TypeError: 'getBoundingClientRect' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.
      2 > [object DOMRect]
```

The equality test shows they are the same object, yet one gives error, the other doesn't.

Further experimentation seems to reveal that the problem is not related to the proxy per se, but to returning a function from a function.  It also reveals that the problem is not related to XUL, as in this case I am using an HTML element:

My code:

```
let gB = {

  getFunction : function() {

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    return div.getBoundingClientRect;
  },  
}
```

When I run:

```
try {
  dump("      1 > "+gB.getFunction()()+"\n");
}catch(e) { dump("ERROR 1 : "+e+"\n"); }
```

Again I get:

```
ERROR 1 : TypeError: 'getBoundingClientRect' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.
```

The proxy example I showed was greatly reduced from what I am trying to accomplish. My working proxy is used to lazily create a complex DOM element structure selectively based on which properties are sought. ie, if tab.linkedBrowser.propertyA is accessed, a function is run which will create the element structure, but if tab.linkedBrowser.propertyB is accessed, it is not, and a subsitute value is returned instead.

I would be happy to receive insight on how to return these functions which use an interface and be able to run them.

I would also be **very** interested in an explanation on how the equality test can show that two different function expressions reference they same object, yet running each of them give different results.

Answer (score 2):

I consider it as bug in Firefox. their methods aren't possible to use on anything except DOM Elements, even on inheriting objects. We have to wait for full ES6 implementation.

My untested proposition is:

```
new Proxy(this.browser, {
    "get": function(target, key, receiver) {
        dump("GET : " + key + "\n");
        if (key in target) {
            let ret = target[key];
            if (typeof ret === 'function') {
                // DOM methods sometimes aren't istances of Function, so we can't directly use func.bind()
                ret = Function.prototype.bind.call(ret, target);
            }
            return ret;
        }
    },
});
```

It has at least few caveats:

- methods will be called with `this` set to original object.
- you can't use `===` to test if method was modified

Comment: Wow, that works, thanks!  Can you explain why two functions that test true for equality give different results?  That's really perplexing to me.

Comment: Is there any way around the /this/ issue?  I am not able to manipulate the calling functions.

Comment: You can't work around `this` issue without rewriting big part of Firefox source code (you're welcome) or creating your own DOM implementation.